# How to build linux based open cv libraries in windows that is .so format using cross compile?

Tags: linux, windows, opencv, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I followed this blog
http://vijaysringeri.blogspot.in/2013/01/building-opencv-libraries-for-linux-on.html
But using mingw,msys and cmake I am able to create only static libraries that is .a format .My target is to build libraries in .so format .Please tell me how to proceed or if you have any other approaches then share it ?

Comment: I fear VM solution would the most appropriate.

Comment: @yegorich yes i was able to built my libraries using linux in vmware but I need to build it using windows and by cross compiling too .Please help if you have anything to share .